# Why we need an angle to for trig ratios?

Tags: trigonometry

Like f(x)=2x+3 is a function. If we input the value of x so it will apply operations on the value of x and give back a result but in trig function i.e. 
                               Sin (X)= opp/hyp
But it doesn't apply operations on the input. So my question is why we need an input for that?

Comment: Sin(x) does not apply simple operations but there is an algorithm to follow: construct a right triangle with an angle $x$. Measure the opp and the hyp and do the division. A function is any kind of assignment of an input value to corresponding output(s).

Comment: If I told you to calculate the value of $\sin$, you would ask me back "okay, but $\sin$ of what?". Plus, not all functions apply operations to it's inputs, or not in the sense of number operations (addition, multiplication, etc..). Think, for instance, a function that for each integer gives how many positive divisors does it have: $\f(6) = 4$, $f(12) = 6$ and so on...

Answer (score 2):

> But it doesn't apply operations on the input.

Your can better ask "why the input isn't (opp,hyp)"? Or (adj,hyp)...

In a first moment, the input can be considered the triangle.

Then we see that similar triangles give the same answer.

What common data have similar triangles?

*The angles*.

$\sin$ and $\cos$ depend of the *angle* between the adjacent side and the hypothenuse.